# Condition to see if there are results for MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a condition that returns true if there are results. How do I do it?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Groups` WHERE `City` = '$city2' LIMIT 12 OFFSET 6");


if (the condition) {

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { ?>
    <a href="/?ciudad=<?php echo $city; ?>&colegio=<?php echo $row['Group']; ?>" class="<?php if ($group == $row['Group']) { echo "selected"; } ?>"><?php echo $row['Group']; ?></a>  <?
    }   
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

There should have something like:

```
if ($result.size > 0) {
  // do this
}
```